# A point difference when calculating same values from SQL/Calculator and Javascript

Tags: javascript, sql-server, calculation

Different Number resulting, When im performing below calculation at SQL side and Javascript side,

```
0.4583 * 3000
```

```js
var i = 0.4583 * 3000
 
console.log(i)
```

> > Result from SQL : `1374.9000`
> >
> > Result from Calculator : `1374.9`
> >
> > Result from JS Console : `1374.8999999999999`
>
> **Expected result : 1374.9000**

Comment: SQL and your calculator use a different number representation than JavaScript (and most other programming languages).

Comment: SO how can i get the same result in both SQL and JS console? @Pointy

Comment: JavaScript uses binary floating point; a value like 9/10 (`.9`) cannot be represented exactly, just like 2/3 cannot be represented exactly in decimal floating point.

Comment: thanks for the quick response